# Accessing role_arn in different folder than where the role was created

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a Terraform structure like:

```
prod
nonprod
applications
+-- continuous/common/iam/iam.tf  <-- create the role
+-- dataflow/firehose/firehose.tf  <-- want to refer to the role created above
```

I don't know how to do this.  In the iam's .tf file I have:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "policy_daily_process_role" {
...
}

output "svc_daily_process_role_arn" {
  value = "${aws_iam_role.policy_daily_process_role.arn}"
}
```

I am not sure how (or if) I can then refer to the svc_daily_process_role_arn from the firehose's .tf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding that you already use modules to manage terraform codes.

So in your case, there should be two modules at least.

```
continuous/common
dataflow/firehose
```

In `continuous/common` module, you have defined `output.tf`

```
output "svc_daily_process_role_arn" {
  value = "${aws_iam_role.policy_daily_process_role.arn}"
}
```

So you create the resources with common module first.

```
module "common" {
  source = "./continuous/common"
  ...
}
```

Now you are fine to refer the output from module `common` with below codes:

```
module "firehost" {
  source = "./dataflow/firehose"

  some_variable = "${module.common.svc_daily_process_role_arn}"
  ...
}
```

Please go through below documents for better understanding.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#outputs

Answer (score 1):

Using Terraform Modules.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html

From a top level make a call to the two subdirectories.

In module 1 (your IAM role) add an output like you have, but ensure it's outputted from module 1.

In module 2 reference it via ${module..}

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using modules (or even if you are), you can use [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html). This means you will save your state in S3 or Consul and then refer to it from anywhere in your code.